# Can "isTemplate" return true for a non-function class member in D?

Tags: d, introspection

I've got a list of class members: `__traits(allMembers, SomeType)`. And I use a trait `__traits(isTemplate, member)` for some element `member` from the list. Consider the result of the trait is true. Does this mean that the member is a function? Or can something else be template in the list from `allMembers`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean it's a function, it means it's a template. That template could either be a templated function, or indeed a template itself.

An example:

```
import std.stdio;
struct Test{
    void fee(T)(){}
    template fi(T){
        void fo(){} // wont get tested...
    }
    void fum(){}
} 

void main(){
    foreach(member; __traits(allMembers, Test)){
        writefln("%s isTemplate: %s", member, __traits(isTemplate, mixin("Test."~member)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fee isTemplate: true
fi isTemplate: true
fum isTemplate: false
```

The thing that is probably tripping you up is you lacking the `mixin`.
If `mixin("Test."~member)` wasn't there, then isTemplate would be testing if `fi` is a template, or `fo` or `fum`, and they're not templates as they dont exist in that namespace.

They only exist in the `Test` structs namespace.